# C++: Как разбить вводящиеся без пробела элементы по "ячейкам" массива?

Tags: c++, массивы, динамические-массивы, ввод, вектор

Условие: 
Вводятся два числа: длина вводимого числа и само число. Задача каждый разряд данного числа последовательно поместить в отдельную ячейку.
Например, вводится: `2 45`.
Тогда мы должны получить массив (или вектор) длиной в два элемента: `x[0] = 5; x[1] = 4;` или `x[0] = 4; x[1] = 5;`.

Основная проблема в том что длина вводимого числа может быть до 10^1000 и я не могу просто присвоить это значение переменной и циклично делением на десять "распилить" ее на элементы. Поэтому, как мне кажется, нужно прямо во время ввода "раскладывать" число по ячейкам, но я не знаю как это сделать)

Пытался через getchar(), но вышла лапша. И еще пытался с вектором:

```
int n, c = 1; cin >> n;
vector<int> v(1);
vector<int>::iterator i;
for (i = v.begin(); i < v.end(); i++) 
{
cin >> *i;
v.resize(v.size()+1);
if(c==n) break;
c++;
}
```

Но и это тоже просто смешно. Скорее всего я банально многого не знаю о свойствах ввода в C++

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Всё просто, число в строку и получите массив char, где ваше 45 станет char test[0] = '4', test[1] = '5', test[2] = EOS
Для этого можно itoa использовать

Comment: Только при этом нужно вычесть из каждого элемента `'0'` - в условии говорится о *числах*, а не о символах. Второй вопрос - о том, что это массив `char`, а не `int`, - не столь принципиальный.

Answer (score 2):

Вы как-то странно (*странно, если не сказать большего* (с) :)) работаете с вектором. Попробуйте так:

```
int n; cin >> n;

vector<int> v;

for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i)
{
    char c;
    cin >> c;
    v.push_back(c-'0');
}
```